# Conditionally display menu for page type in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am relatively unfamiliar with Wordpress and I am creating a custom theme for a client. I would like to either display or remove the main menu depending on the page type. I have researched several options like removing the navigation from header.php and referencing it separately and also making the menu conditional which is preferable.

I have a custom page type in my theme called 'landing page' on which I would like the menu to be never be displayed, though it will be on every other page. Ultimately there will be a lot of these and I would rather I didn't have to intervene.

I would rather not duplicate my header.php file but I can only find reference to displaying the menu conditionally like below by page name or ID which seems ridiculous.

```
<?php
 if (is_page('contact')){
 <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/headerA.php'); ?>
}
elseif (is_page('gallery')){
 <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/headerB.php'); ?>
}
else {
 <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/headerA.php'); ?>
}
?>
```

Rather than including files as above, I will put the whole thing into my header and just make the navigation conditional. Does anyone know how I should approach this using my custom page type landing page rather than by page name so every page created with that type will never have a menu?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about a Custom Post Type (CPT) or a page called `landing-page`?

They are completely different. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

In any event, this will work for a custom post type or a page:

```
if ( !is_singular( 'custom-post-type-name-or-page-slug-here' ) ) {

get_template_part('menu');

}
```

**It says:** "If this page is not a single page or a CPT, load the file menu.php from the theme folder."

See also http://codex.wordpress.org/Include_Tags:

> The get_template_part() tag includes the file {slug}.php or
>   {slug}-{name}.php from your current theme's directory, a custom
>   Include Tags other than header, sidebar, footer.

Comment: Unless I completely misunderstand the concept of Custom Post Types (which is possible) I don't think it's either of those. It's nothing to do with posts or blogs, and not a page I have created through the admin panel, though that is were I have selected the 'template'.

I am creating theme and the part I wish to edit is what I would typically describe as a Page Template.

Comment: OK, but what is the slug - the permalink - of the "landing page" you're naming in your question? This has to be a page you have created in admin. The conditional above will go in a page template, like page.php, or header.php, but you have to create a page in admin called "landing page" that you don't want the menu to appear on.

Comment: Never mind! Thanks for your help. Using your answer I have found a solution using 'if( !is_page_template' which is exactly what I was looking for. I needed the menu to be conditionally excluded on all Pages using specific Templates without needing to know page slugs, permalinks or IDs in advance as some content will be dynamically created.

Comment: Yes, is_page_template will work and is a different but better approach to what you want to do.