# How to fix WordPress Theme "Conditional Menus" for WP V5.1?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

The theme "Conditional Menus" will not load in V5.1, reporting an issue with styles.css

There are requests in the WordPress forum for the author to fix since V5.0, but these have gone unanswered.  I've tried adding an empty styles.css to the zip, but that didn't help.

1. What else can I try to make the theme V5.1 compatible?
2. Alternatively, is there another theme that can acheive hiding menu options depending on the open page?
3. Or perhaps better still, can I do this with CSS without using a theme?

I've looked at [Conditionally display menu for page type in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599699/conditionally-display-menu-for-page-type-in-wordpress) and that doesn't help me.